# Test method with no parameters

Tags: java, junit

I am quite new to testing in Java, and wonder if there is a way to test a class like this?
What I especially is wondering about, is how to test a methods such as the "calculateCustoms" as it does not take any input parameter..

```
public class CustomsCalculator {
    
    private double litresWine, litresBeer;
    
    public void setLitresWine(double litresWine) {
        checkDoubleNotNegative(litresWine);
        this.litresWine = litresWine;
    }
    
    public void setLitresBeer(double litresBeer) {
        checkDoubleNotNegative(litresBeer);
        this.litresWineOverQuota = litresWineOverQuota;
    }

    
    public double getLitresWine() {
        return litresWine;
    }
    
    public double getLitresBeer() {
        return litresBeer;
    }

    
    
    public void checkDoubleNotNegative(double number) {
        if (number < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative value not allowed.");
        }
    }
    
    
    public double calculateCustoms() {
            double wineFee = 13.0*getLitresWineOverQuota();
            double beerFee = 11.0*getLitresBeerOverQuota();

            
            double totalFee =  wineFee + beerFee;
            return totalFee;
    }
}
```

Comment: but you need to set values in **setLitresWine, setLitresBeer**

Comment: Create an instance, invoke the setters, make sure that `calculateCustoms` returns what you expect.

Comment: Aside: if you make `checkDoubleNotNegative` return `number`, you can write `this.value = checkDoubleNotNegative(value);`, just makes it a bit neater. Also, not sure about your `setLitresBeer` method, doesn't work like `setLitresWine` does (if it compiles at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a test, you can follow this step:

1. Prepare the context: instantiate `CustomsCalculator`, call `setLitresWine()` and `setLitresBeer()` with non negatove value.
2. Call the tested method: `calculateCustoms()`.
3. Validate the result

```
public class CustomsCalculatorShould {

  @Test
  void calculate_the_customs_of_1_wine_and_1_beer() {
    // Prepare the context
    CustomsCalculator customsCalculator = new CustomsCalculator();
    customsCalculator.setLitresWine(1);
    customsCalculator.setLitresBeer(1);
    // Call the tested method
    double totalFee = customsCalculator.calculateCustoms()
    // Validate the result
    assertEquals(expectedResult, totalFee);
  }
}
```

`expectedResult` must be replaced by the correct value. Your code don't show the `getLitresWineOverQuota()` and `getLitresBeerOverQuota()` implemtations so I don't calculate the correct value.

You should test `setLitresWine()` and `setLitresBeer()` too.

This is one of several testing methodologies :)